# Can I use Visual Studio to clone remote github repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to clone some remote repository(like github) in Visual Studio 2015 Community?
I just downloaded Visual Studio 2015 free version, I noticed it can support git, but seem to only support local git repository.
that mean I need to use 3rd git client to clone remote repository, then import to Visual Studio.
Is it a better way to do that?
Thanks,
-S-G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to enter directly a git repo url, under the `Local Git Repositories` section of the `Connect` panel:

[image: http://www.malgreve.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/VisualStudio-Clone-Git-Repositories.png]

[Visual Studio with Git](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh850437.aspx) has an [updated page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/get-started), with a field you should be able to fill with the url of your choice:

[image: https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/_img/get-started/VSClone2.png]

Comment: And there is also a [github extension](https://visualstudio.github.com/) that you could have installed during Vs2015 install (just a checkbox to check) or through the VS extension manager, if you find it more convenient to clone a github repository...

Comment: Thank you for helping, it is correct. I missed that out because it is concealed by a warning message banner.

Comment: @smokinggun Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I found this to be a bit confusing because there are two clone links.  The first is under a `GitHub` section, this only allows you to clone repos that you have access to using a search filter.  The second clone link is where you describe under the `Local Git Repositories`.  However, this may have been due to me installing the Git for Windows tools as well as the VS extensions.

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler yes, it is possible those clone two links are coming from two different extensions.